# Как правильно выполнить запрос board.getTopics при помощи библиотеки vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно установить правильную последовательность выполнения запроса к методу board.getTopics API «ВКонтакте» с помощью библиотеки vk_api.

Моё текущее решение:

```py
import vk_api
vk = vk_session.get_api()
vk_session.auth() 
vk.board.getTopics(group_id=37273781)
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(“login”, “password”)
```

Правильно ли я указал последовательность выполнения запроса?

Answer (score 2):

Верный порядок команд следующий:

```py
import vk_api
    
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(“login”, “password”)
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()
vk.board.getTopics(group_id=37273781)
```